# Cannot FindWindow parent process' window, neither terminate parent

Tags: c, winapi

I have a parent process, that spawns a child process. The child process' aim is to restart the parent process by terminating it, waiting a few seconds, and then starting it again. I have no way of detecting if the parent runs with admin privileges or not, but the child runs without admin privileges. The parent has a hidden window that has a unique window class, by which the window can be found and WM_CLOSE sent to it. In certain installations, however, the child's call to FindWindow() with the class' identifier fails - no window is found. However, enumerating  all processes in the system, via EnumProcesses(), then opening each process, calling GetModuleFileNameEx() successfully finds the parent's process by its executable path, which is known and fixed. However, calling TerminateProcess() on the process handle returns an access denied error (5). Setting SeDebugPrivilege fails, because the child does not have  escalated privileges.
The above situation occurs only on a few test machines, on most machines it works as expected - the window can be found, and trying to kill the parent via TerminateProcess() succeeds. My question is - is there some isolation mode between the child and parent configured on some machines, so that FindWindow() and TerminateProcess() fail, or is there another reason for that?

Comment: Is the parent starting the child to run as another user?

Comment: No, runs as same user! I have verified this by getting the username of the parent and the child process, and it is the same. However, is it possible that the domain differs or something like that?

Comment: Is there anything in common to the failing (test) machines?  What is the general character of the machines it succeeds on versus the machines it fails on?

Comment: I have no idea, the tests are done remotely.

Comment: It sounds like the parent process is running with admin privileges and the child is not. Accessing the parent from the child is therefore blocked by security.

Comment: Perhaps the machines that work are running Windows XP, and the ones that don't are Vista or Windows 7.  A lower integrity level child process will be blocked from sending messages to a window of higher integrity level on the newer versions of Windows.  On XP, there were no integrity levels, so this may not apply.  Browsers often take advantage of integrity levels for security.  Is your parent process a browser by chance?

Comment: I also thought that the problem is parent=higher child=lower privilege. However, as far as I know, it is not possible a parent process with admin privileges to start a child process and the child to be with user privileges - please correct me if I am wrong. I say this because in installers, it is quite tricky to start the app with ordinary user privileges - there need to be two installer processes, first(outer) run with user rights, which runs the second(inner), second has a manifest requesting admin privileges, it does the actual install, then the outer runs the app with lower privileges.

Comment: Ok, some more info I received - the OS is WinXP. The parent and child process have the same user. The child cannot set SeDebugPrivilege, and also cannot find the systray icon, via FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL). TerminateProcess() returns error 5.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link may help you a lot :)
[GetParentProcessID](http://www.codeforge.com/read/69075/GetParentProcessID.cpp__html)

This source just teaches you that the function from ntdll **NtQueryInformationProcess** stores the parent ID as **InheritedFromUniqueProcessId** in the **PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION** structure